# Layout breaking down - how to get it even/aligned?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Please see designer's picture:

[image]

Now see what I'm getting:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_back">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_selected"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Home"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_g"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="This is long string that pushes layout"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/available_g"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Available"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/completed_g"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Completed"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/mail_g"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Mail"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Questions. How do I:

1. Make sure no matter what - screen broken down to 5 even segments - so all buttons even no matter text inside.
2. If one button pushes layout down - how do I make sure other buttons fill that vertical space as well? Like home button is not all way down - you can see where **nav_selected** ends
3. I have icons in PNG in 3 sizes as per google format. I want to have some padding for **drawableTop** if possible so icons look smaller on my screen - closer to what designers screen look.

Thanks!

Comment: You also have another problem - your designers have designed a port from another OS instead of a UI for Android. ;)

Comment: @adamp No kidding.. I asked them to move bar to the top at least. It's what they used to, those designers :) Now I'm trying to come up with Base activity from which I will inherit. Will see if it works out..
P.S. App doesn't exist in other OS

Comment: You might want to pass along these links to your designers, both are talks from Google I/O on Android UI design patterns. The first is from last year, the second is from this year: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y

Comment: Well, even though it does look like iPhone app - current design fits well with what need to be accomplished. It's pretty much Android tabbed UI. And we have plans migrating it ot iOS later so it's OK I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about layout_weight on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) in the section about LinearLayouts. That is the attribute you're going to want to use to get the views to all get the same width. I am not super familiar with its implementation but I would think you probably wont want width set to wrap_content when you do it that way.

Edit:

> Tip: To create a proportionate size
>   layout on the screen, create a
>   container view group object with the
>   layout_width and layout_height
>   attributes set to fill_parent; assign
>   the children height or width to 0
>   (zero); then assign relative weight
>   values to each child, depending on
>   what proportion of the screen each
>   should have.

This seems like what you want to do.

Comment: I use layout_weight already. I also have no idea what to replace "wrap_content" with. I want it to be 20% and AFAIK android doesn't do this.. :(

Comment: Thanks! That fixed issue #1 :) Do you have any ideas for #2 and #3?

Comment: If you put them in a tableRow (or Horizontal LinearLayout) layout with layout_height="wrap_content" then each item has a   layout_height="fill_parent"  it should work to your expectations.   I would like to also echo that you aren't designing a UI to android norms, however.

Comment: @Eric Thanks! I know about design, but I'm not designer and won't be able to do better. Unfortunately. Seems like its OK. See here:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/04/5-tips-for-converting-ios-ui-to-android.html

Comment: I was more referring to the icons used.  You are indeed doing right though by putting the navbar at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use GridView ( or even ListView, Gallery) and create simple adapter, where you will override getView() method to inflate your layout. I think that layout is pretty easy to create and it will be the same for each button. In addition, you'll be able to scroll if there's more than 5 elements.